# Replace substring of a string using REGEX in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am using notepad++ and I want to create an automation in order to replace some strings.

In this case I am going to deal with the `a href` tag.

So, I will give 3 examples of some lines I have in my code :

**01**)

`<a href="https://url.com" class="logo"><img src="urlurlurlurl" alt=""></a>`

**02**)

```
<a href="https://url.com" class="logo"><img src="urlurlurlurl" alt="">
         </a>
```

**03**)

```
<a href="https://url.com"><img src="urlurlurlurl" alt=""></a>
```

**04**)

```
<a href="https://url.com">link</a>
```

So, if I wanted to replace the full `a href` tag above in all 4 cases, I would use this one : `<a href(.*?)a>`

Now, I am trying to think of a way to replace the url within the a href tag only.

I tried using that :

```
href="(?s)(.*?)"|href ="(?s)(.*?)"
```

and it works fine because I also take into consideration that there might be a space.

But now in the replace window I have to include `href=""`

[image]

Is there a way to make it search for the `a href` tags and then replace a specific substring of it?

I want to know because there are cases where I have other tags that include a url and I want to replace it. But a generic replacement for all the strings that are included within quotes ("string") would not be good as I do not to replace all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negated class to match everything before and after the `href` like,

```
(a[^>]*href\s*=\s*")[^"]*
```

replace with capture group `$1REPLACE_STRING`

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/NCHycg/1)

**What it does?**

- `a[^>]*` Matches `a` followed by anything other than a closing `>`.
- `href\s*=\s*"` Matches `href="`. Till here is captured in group 1.
- `[^"]*` Matches anything other than `"`. This form the url that you want to replace.